# input in div to fill entire table cell

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

There is an input inside a div inside a table cell.

```
<td align="left" id="subformAttachments_Htmltable1td10" style="border:solid 1px black;width:316px;" class="tbldroppable ui-droppable formMenu ui-resizable">
    <div itemtype="text" id="subformAttachments_divtextDescription_1" ismobilectl="true" style="display: inline-block; position: static; height: 36px; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 5px; z-index: 0; width: 100%;" class="input-large ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle formMenu ui-resizable" datatype="text" format="">
        <input type="text" id="subformAttachments_textDescription_1" placeholder="" name="subformAttachments_textDescription_1" class="" value="" style="width:100%;height:100%" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</td>
```

But the text box sticks out on the right.

[image]

How can I make the text box fit better, i.e. fill entire table cell and be centered? I can only edit styles but not add or remove elements.

This page uses jQuery and Bootstrap.

Comment: Try margin left

Comment: Have you tried to make the table cell editable?

https://jsfiddle.net/uzo6emr1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving your td an exact width of 316px and then giving the DIV margins of 5px, why not give your input the td width, minus the margin size. (306px)

```
 <table>        
   <!-- the td has an exact width of 316px -->
   <td align="left" id="subformAttachments_Htmltable1td10" style="border:solid 1px black;width:316px;" class="tbldroppable ui-droppable formMenu ui-resizable">
      
         <!-- your DIV has margins of 5px. So subtract the margins from the input width to get it to fit in the td properly -->
         <div itemtype="text" id="subformAttachments_divtextDescription_1" ismobilectl="true" style="display: inline-block; position: static; height: 36px; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 5px; z-index: 0;" class="input-large ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle formMenu ui-resizable" datatype="text" format="">
          
         <!-- Change the width to 306px -->
         <input type="text" id="subformAttachments_textDescription_1" placeholder="" name="subformAttachments_textDescription_1" class="" value="" style="width:306px;height:100%" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
   </td>
</table>
```